# How to swap a specific character from a matrix with a blank space

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm doing a simple game using C and nCurses. When i press space, my character shoot a missile across the map. In the map i have barriers that are matrices composed of '@' chars. Once my missile hit one of these barrier, i want to delete this char from my matrix, but at the moment, i delete this char only with `mvaddch(y, x, ' ');`. Then, when i want to pass over the coordinates where the first matrix was drawn, my character freezes, as if the characters are invisible.
This is my barrier:

```
char matrixB[3][8]  = {   
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'}
};
```

For example, if the last char is hitted by the missile, i want to have

```
char matrixB[3][8]  = {   
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@','@','@','@',' '}
};
```

Comment: `matrixB[i][j]=' '` ??

Comment: Already tried something like that, but I think I need to know until i have to do the for condition to know the exact position that i have to 'delete'. At the moment, when i start the game i draw these barriers at exact coordinates...